# How to run a PowerShell command in UWP?

Tags: powershell, uwp, external, sandbox

How to run a PowerShell command in UWP?

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    PowerShellInstance.AddCommand(".\fpcalc.exe " + file.Path + " > out.txt");
}
```

Comment: Have you imported it?

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image. It's hard to read, prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post.

Answer (score 5):

Because UWP apps run in a sandbox, you cannot directly execute another processes or run PowerShell scripts. However, you can utilize `Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher` if you declare such capability in your app to launch a full trust process (like a console application) which can safely execute such script.

You need to add a restricted `fullTrust` capability to your app's `Package.appxmanifest`.

You can learn more about full trust processes in UWP from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher), [UWP samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples) or blogposts like the [excellent blogpost series](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/) from Stefan Wick.

Comment: If the answer resolved your issue, you could [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it as accepted. But please do not post multiple questions on the same thread.

Comment: Sorry. UWP Access Denied when debugging on Local Machine ?

Comment: That is most likely a different problem, please mark this answer as resolved and post new question :-)